# opening the modal for second time redirecting to 404

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a button and clicking that button will pop up a modal and that modal contains a component that is loaded by route(`path: question`). when I press that button for the 1st time it will pop up a modal and everything will be fine but when I close the modal and again pressing the button for the 2nd time redirecting to the 404 page.

suppose when modal opens for the 1st time the route will be `localhost:3000/testing/5kjkf/(test:question)` and after closing the modal the route is not changing. I have been trying to solve this from the past 5hrs. any help is very much appreciated. thank you.

xyz.component.html

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openQuestionsModal(quesModal)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Create Question</button>
          <ng-template #quesModal>
              <div class="modal-content modal-lg">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </ng-template>
```

xyz.component.ts

```
openQuestionsModal(template) {
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { test: 'question' } }], {queryParams: { testId: this.test._id }, relativeTo: this.route, skipLocationChange:true });
```

}

xyz.modules.ts

```
        { path: '', component: AComponent, outlet: 'test', children:[
        {
            path: 'question', loadChildren: 'app/admin/questions/questions.module#QuestionsModule'
        }
    ]},
```

Comment: Can you create a codeSandbox/stackblitz to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @VimalPatel its very difficult as it involves many other components

Comment: I think on your modal's close event you need to navigate back